# Magento 2: How to crawl custom/dynamic URL's?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, magento2-enterprise, crawler

We need to crawl the custom/dynamic URLs. Is there any way?

Suppose we have a URL like https://www.test.com/stores/awt

and it's coming from a custom module and **/awt** is dynamic it changes as per requirement, is there any way to crawl those URLs.

I have set tags as well:

canonical: https://www.test.com/stores/awt

robots: INDEX,FOLLOW

Thanks in advance.